# Javascript - regex from "{"task":"' + t '",.*"}" return whole string

Tags: javascript, regex, json

I have a file that contains JSON array of tasks:

currently the file contains:

```
[
 {"task":"hey", "checked":"0", "data1":"", "data2":"", "data3":""},
 {"task":"there", "checked":"0", "data1":"jiojoi", "data2":"", "data3":""}
]
```

I want to isolate a signle task so I use the following code:

```
var taskExp = new RegExp('{"task":"' + taskName + '",.*"}', '');

// Get the task
var task = taskExp.exec(text);
```

in this specific case, if `taskName = "hey"`, it returns the whole string. (2 tasks).

if `taskName = "there"`, it's ok.

Why? thanks in advance.

Comment: `.*` mathes a string up to the end of the line.

Comment: How about not using regexes to filter out tasks?

Comment: @stribizhev The pattern I want is: '{"task":"taskname",<everything>}. how to fix?

Comment: @Billie: See Cerbrus's answer.

Answer (score 5):

It's a bad idea to use regexes to filter out properties of a JSON string.
Parse it into an object (/array), then use `filter`, instead.

Assuming `text` is your JSON string:

```
var dataArray = JSON.parse(text),
    taskName = "someTaskName";

var result = dataArray.filter(function(item){
    return item.task === taskName;
});
```

Then, `result` is an array of all matching tasks.

Comment: Thanks. can you please explain why it is a bad idea?

Comment: It's inefficient, and the regex will break as soon as your JSON gets more complicated. You're working with arrays, so why not make sure you're capable of using built-in array functionalities?